# How to use attribute URI in ANT MacroDef task?

Tags: ant, uri, macrodef

I read doc page on http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html, but I can understand.
There are no examples.
How to use attribute URI in ANT MacroDef task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution here:
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ant-user/200606.mbox/%3C4489507F.5050503@mindspring.com%3E

```
 <project name="test" xmlns:me="x.y.z">
   <macrodef name="sample" uri="x.y.z">
       <sequential>
          <echo>Hello world</echo>
       </sequential>
   </macrodef>

   <me:sample/>
 </project>
```